# Remove DropDownList Value After Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I dont know if its the way am wording my question but all i want is a way in which when a user selects a option within a drop down menu and then presses submit the value in the drop down that was selected not to be shown there. I have tried the following:

```
<div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("GameIDFK", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ViewBag.GameIDFK)
            </div>


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tblReview tblreview, FormCollection formCollection)
       {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    db.tblReviews.Add(tblreview);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                   // return RedirectToAction("Index");  
                }
                 int gameid=Convert.ToInt32(formCollection["GameIDFK"]);
                var userGames = (from g in db.tblGames where g.UserName== User.Identity.Name && g.GameID!=gameid select g).ToList();
                ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(userGames, "GameID", "GameName");
                return View(new tblReview { UserName = @User.Identity.Name });
    }
```

this just removes one value and when another is selected the pervious one comes back, also when i refresh the page all values return.

I have also tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#GameIDFK').change(function() {
            $('option:selected', this).remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

what this does is when i click the value it totaly vanishs and when i refresh the value comes back.

I am using MVC3 C# and want a way in which when a user selects a game for example GTAIV and presses submit the value from the drop down GTAIV to be gone even when i refreash, or log out and log in again i want the value from the drop to be gone from the drop down but i dont want to delete it from the database, just want the selected value in the drop down to go once the submit button is pressed.

My controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Game.Models;

namespace Game.Controllers
{ 
    public class ReviewController : Controller
    {
        private gamezoneDBEntities db = new gamezoneDBEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Review/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var Info = db.tblReviews.Include(x => x.tblGame).Where(UserInfo => UserInfo.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).ToList();
            return View(Info); 
        }

        //
        // GET: /Review/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Review/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var userGames = db.tblGames.Where(g => g.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(userGames, "GameID", "GameName");
            return View(new tblReview { UserName = @User.Identity.Name });

        } 

        //
        // POST: /Review/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(tblReview tblreview)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tblReviews.Add(tblreview);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            var userGames = db.tblGames.Where(g => g.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(userGames, "GameID", "GameName");
            return View(new tblReview { UserName = @User.Identity.Name });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Review/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
            ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames, "GameID", "GameName", tblreview.GameIDFK);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Review/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(tblReview tblreview)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tblreview).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames, "GameID", "GameName", tblreview.GameIDFK);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Review/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Review/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {            
            tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
            db.tblReviews.Remove(tblreview);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

My model:

```
namespace Game.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblReview
    {
        public int ReviewID { get; set; }
        public string Recomendation { get; set; }
        public string AvoidOrBuy { get; set; }
        public string Score { get; set; }
        public int GameIDFK { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual tblGame tblGame { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My View:

```
@model Game.tblReview

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>tblReview</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recomendation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recomendation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recomendation)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AvoidOrBuy)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AvoidOrBuy)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AvoidOrBuy)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Score)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Score)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Score)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GameIDFK, "tblGame")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("GameIDFK", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GameIDFK)

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I have been at this for weeks an have no outcome please help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

I analysed your problem and it seems that you will have to make somekind of a persistence mechanism to remember user choices. For example user deletes GTA IV, then you have to modyfi database and store ID of the dropdown element, ID of user and also boolean IsVisible. On refresh you will have to download both lists and show elements that are visible.

With this kind of data i don't know which persistance implementation would be better. You need to analyse your user story beacuse maybe you can store this "Visibility" choice in the cookie. It depends on your functionality and requirements.

EDIT:

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(tblReview tblreview, string selectedValue)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(tblreview).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames.Where(x=>x.GameID != tblreview.GameIDFK), "GameID", "GameName");
    return View(tblreview);
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with am asking for all i want is a way in which the value in the drop down to be cleared once the submit button is selected. That is all. I dnt want the value reapearing once i loged out or once i refeashed the page. I just want the value gone once selected and teh enter button is pressed

Comment: Ok then you have to postback selected value from dropdown and when you are creating ViewBag.GameIDFK use Where to exclude this value from the list. You can achieve this in form of hidden input text and another parameter in the action method.

Comment: can you please provide some code thanks cause I have provided attempts, and if you know how to do this then i would be greatful if you could tell me thanks

Comment: Does nothing the value in the drop down is still there, does not work

Comment: @user1137472 hmm i created my own test project and tried this. It works for me ... ok turn on DebugMode and check if tblreview.GameIDFK is not null also tblGames what kind of collection is it ?

Comment: GamIDFK i can confirm is not null and what do you mean by collection?

Comment: Why is this on edit? when it cleary says on my question and have mentioned to you that i want the value to be cleared from a drop down list when the user presses create? this could not have worked on yours as its not even in the context of which i asked

Comment: Your code does not work i adapted it for the create I dont know what it is that you got working, but it is not working on mine

Comment: I have just made a sample ... and tbh right now i am confused ;) Don't know how what you really want to achieve.

Comment: all i want is my dropdown on my create page to clear the game name from the list once the user presses submit so when a game for example GTAIV is selected and a review is written the name GTAIV gets cleared from the drop down, i dont know how clear to say it :(

Comment: Ok then if it is something like ... I m opening create site select game to review i create a review click submit. And on next refresh i see dropdown without game already reviewed then it seems like you have to modyfi tblGames and have a information like "Finished in db"  in order to persist this kind of data.